# Classification of Bayesian probabilities

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

I have run a series of Bayesian models with flat priors in which I obtain a posterior probability distribution for my coefficient of interest. The reviewer of my paper wishes us to classify these probability according to different strengths of evidences (strong, moderate, weak etc..). I have seen this done with Bayes factor, e.g., [Lee and Wagenmakers' classification](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-018-01189-8/tables/1?shared-article-renderer)

I wish to avoid running the models with and without the coefficient. Instead, I thought I could compare the posterior and prior probability. However, I have uninformative priors so I think Bayes factor would not work(?). But I wonder whether I can still follow this classification, e.g., under the null prior, I expect 50% of the coefficient to be negative. While my posterior probability is 5%. From that, can I infer a Bayes factor of 10 (0.5/0.05), which would be strong evidence?

Or is there another classification scheme I could use?

Thanks for any help and especially any references?

Comment: The Bayes factor is a likelihood ratio of the marginal likelihood of two competing hypotheses. So you could use it to compare a hypothesis of a negative coefficient vs. of a positive, but I do not see why do you use it to compare priors to posteriors.

Comment: i got the idea from here https://easystats.github.io/bayestestR/articles/bayes_factors.html when it discusses the Savage-Dickey ratio

Comment: Interesting... But that article suggested the BF to be a ratio of point values, while your 50% and 5% are more of integrals. Should not you instead divide the posterior distro by the prior pointwise, and then classify the result's regions by thresholding against whatever the strong evidence is decreed to be?

Comment: I wonder if anyone has new thoughts/evidence on this?